# Change answer that got awarded a bounty because I was unaware of the bad bounty criteria

Tags: support, bounty

I offered a bounty on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39985856/getting-client-certificate-to-work-for-mutual-authentication-using-swift-3-and-a) with the intention of giving the original poster and answerer (the same person) some extra credit AND to maybe even attract some more useful answers.

It attracted a few views and upvotes but unfortunately the only answer it attracted was and is a bad and incorrect one since the answers tackles a different problem.

I did let the bounty expire expecting it to be awarded to the top answer or at least for some kind of indication to what answer it would be awarded to if I did not manually award it. Id did not want to manually award it since my expectation was the top answer would get the bounty and I did not want to take some time off the bounty period during which the question got more attention.

**Is it possible for me or some moderator given the above explanation to fully award the original bounty to the answer which is a correct and perfectly working one?**

Further question(s):

- is there an indication I missed that shows which answer will get the bounty if I do not manually award it?
- am I not allowed to put up another 100 point bounty on the question and immediately award it to the OP (I want to give credit to him after all)

Comment: Afaik, you are just SOL here. I dont think a mod will overturn a bounty. It was awarded following the rules, even if you dont necessarily agree with the end result:/. Your best bet is indeed to re-bounty

Comment: The top answer with minimum two votes posted after the bounty was placed gets the bounty if you let it auto-award IIRC. You started the bounty on 6th nov and OPs answer was posted on 3rd Nov so he wasntt going to get it auto-awarded in any case

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty has the answers to your further question(s). Might want to read the fancy manual ;).

Comment: No, mods cannot change how the bounty was awarded.

Comment: I believe you get 24 hours between the bounty ending, so that no newer answers are eligible, and it being auto-awarded. This gives you some time to decide which is the best answer without worrying about discouraging any additional answerers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible for me or some moderator given the above explanation to fully award the original bounty to the answer which is a correct and perfectly working one?

Whether they can or not, I'd just take it as a learning experience and move on.

> is there an indication I missed that shows which answer will get the bounty if I do not manually award it?

The answer which will be auto-awarded is selected at the moment of decision for the automatic system. Since it takes into account voting, and vote totals can change, that determination can only be made when it is actually being awarded. So no, there is no indicator as to which answer will be auto-awarded the bounty.

The point of the auto-awarding system is strictly to reward effort created by the bounty when it seems deserved, yet the person giving the bounty did not feel like awarding the answer. It would be unfair for someone to go through the effort of posting a good answer (based on voting), only for the bounty giver to decide to give them nothing.

As such, the auto-award system ignores any answers that were not created during the bounty period.

> am I not allowed to put up another 100 point bounty on the question and immediately award it to the OP (I want to give credit to him after all)

Kinda. You can put another bounty on it. However, you have to bump up the cost of the bounty.

Comment: To the last point, the answer is no.  The minimum bounty amount increases for each successive bounty, so he couldn't post another 100 point bounty; it'd have to be a 200 point bounty.

Comment: @Servy: Noted and fixed.

Comment: FYI, no, mods cannot change how the bounty was awarded.